# Array from function with two variables averaged over one variable without for loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, optimization

I have two numpy arrays t and f. Now I want to create a third array N according to some mathematical formula which takes two parameters (t and f). I want it to be of the same shape as f by averaging the values of N for each f over all t, as done below.

```
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0,4,100)
f = np.linspace(10,15,50)

N = np.zeros(len(f))

for i in range(len(f)):
   eq = np.sin(t)*np.exp(t*f[i])
   N[i] = np.mean(eq)
```

As I have demonstrated, this can be easily done with a for loop. However, I want to improve computation time by removing this for loop. Is there an effective way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. You can skip the loop and do the operation in a single line if you do a bit of vectorization.

```
t,f = t.reshape(-1,1), f = f.reshape(-1,1) #Reshape for matrix multiplication
N = (np.sin(t)*np.exp(t*f.T)).mean(axis = 0)
```